# Using Mosaicking Images in Erdas software

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat, mosaic, erdas-imagine

Do you know any dissertation which has written about Mosaic briefly?

I did the Mosaic for my Landsat images and I want to explain and write about it.

Comment: Your title says Erdas (presumably Imagine) but you have an ArcGIS tag (presumably for Desktop) - which are you using?

Comment: I use Erdas so i want to write about Mosaicking but i really dont know what shall i write so i add all of thw stages but i want to write nicly but i couldnot

Comment: What are you interested in learning about the mosaic that you cannot learn from the software help sites?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find an ERDAS Imagine description along the lines of what I think you are looking for.

However, a blog posting called **[Raster Image Processing Tips and Tricks — Part 2: Mosaicking](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/10/26/georef2/)** is from the ArcGIS for Desktop perspective and may help you.